# a group with specific orders of elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I want to find a group with elements of order $1,2,3,4$ and $5$  (at least one of each order). 
All I can say is that the order of the group is $60$ itself, but cannot find the correct one.
Please let me know about your solutions too.

Comment: you mean any group of order $60$??

Comment: How do you know the order of the group is $60$?

Comment: The groups  $\mathbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$ for $n\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ are possible solutions. Do you want to actually have an element of order $n$ for each $n\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ in the group? That would be more difficult.

Comment: Because the order of elements must divide the order the group. And I meant the group's elements are of the orders $1,2,3,4,5$ and no others.

Comment: Why doesn't the cyclic group of order $60$ not work for you?

Comment: The cyclic group of order sixty contains elements of orders $6,10,12,15,20,40$ and $60$ itself that we do not want.

Comment: @mathmax, just construct the Cartesian product of those.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One example is the alternating group $A_6$.

All groups with this property have been classified in the following paper.

> R. Brandl and W.J. Shi, *Finite groups whose element orders are consecutive integers*, J. Algebra 143, (1991), 388-400. [DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693%2891%2990271-9)

In the above article Brandl and Shi classify all finite groups which have at least one element of order $1,\ 2,\ \ldots,\ n$, and none of any other order. It turns out that such groups exist only for $n \leq 8$. Another interesting result is that a finite group $G$ has $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ as its set of element orders if and only if $G \cong A_7$.

Comment: Mikko very interesting answer! +1 from me.

Answer (score 3):

If you really insist that your group does a element of order $4,$ then there is no such group of order $60$ satisfying the conditions: for if $G$ were such a group, it would have a cyclic Sylow $2$-subgroup, and then a normal subgroup $N$ of order $15,$ and furthermore $N$ would be cyclic, so would have an element of order $15$ (thanks to the comment of Hagen von Eitzen for shortening the argument). Clearly a group of order $60$ has to contain elements of order $1,2,3$ and $5,$ and there is only one group of order $60$ up to isomorphism which contains elements of just these orders.

Comment: Already $N$ would have an element of order $15$.

Comment: Yes, that is true! So I am guilty of overkill.

Comment: $A_5$ is of order 60 satisfying those conditions ,but it does not have element of order $4$.

Comment: Yes, I know. As I said in my answer, there is no group of order $60$ which has elements just of order $1,2,3,4$ and $5$.

Comment: Note that $S_{5}$ comes close, but has order $120$ and contain elements of order $6$.

Comment: Thank you very much. And if it is not the case that the order of group is $60$ could we find a group of those conditions ?

Comment: @GeoffRobinson: Actually there are more examples if you look at the reference in my answer. For example $\operatorname{SmallGroup}(960, 11357)$, which is a semidirect product $SL(2,4) \ltimes N$, where $N$ direct sum of two natural $SL(2,4)$-modules. But $A_7$ is uniquely determined by its set of element orders.

Comment: @MikkoKorhonen : Thanks for pointing that out- I overlooked it.